# Can I draw something like Wheel of Fortune using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css, css-transitions

I wish to draw a Wheel of Fortune using just CSS and jQuery.  I don't want to use any images.

Also, I want to have at least **8 segments** in the circle and properly align each text word vertically in each segment. Here's a photo to illustrate:

[image]

Once I have this working I then can use `CSS3 rotate` property.

Any idea how could I do this?

Comment: Using HTML Canvas: [How to Draw a Wheel of Fortune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850201/how-to-draw-a-wheel-of-fortune/33850748?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C56.9912#33850748)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a **Spinning Wheel Demo** done in HTML5 using Canvas: [**LINK**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130216051045/http://www.dougtesting.net/winwheel/index.html)
[image]

Direct download to the project demo files : [**ZIP**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130216051045/http://www.dougtesting.net/winwheel/winwheel_source.zip)

---

**EDIT:** Here is a different tutorial demo:
[**Creating a roulette wheel using html5 canvas**](https://web.archive.org/web/20120208142814/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas)

Comment: this one was absolutely perfect..just what i wanted..thanks :)

Comment: but i am actually trying to spin the wheel using CSS3 animation property..And the power options must only alter the speed of spinning using CSS3 again which is possible am sure

Comment: Those two demos are not my work and provided by those authors to use as required. A good jQuery plugin to use for rotation is [**jqueryrotate**](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples).

Comment: Ok..now i have tried my hands on some CSS code..u can see it here [link](http://codejigz.com/demos/wheeloffortune/wheel.html).. So how do i ease the movemment of wheel down slowly on clicking stop button..

Comment: I'm not sure. Consider making a new Stackoverflow Question.

Comment: Its awesome.Can you let me know how to get selected value?

Comment: I like this one :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is another example of a [spinning wheel](https://blog.bramp.net/post/2011/07/27/html5-canvas-lunch-wheel/) using a Canvas

[image: Spinning JavaScript wheel]

Answer (score 2):

Check this link -> http://joelb.me/blog/2011/css-mask-tutorial-rotating-image-gallery/

It contains an introductory tutorial to somewhat you need. Check for the `JS 2d Transformation` library code at github too.

Comment: css-mask uses images..i just want to use colors instead and also have to write text on it..will it still be useful ?

Comment: @Jigar Yes why not, u need to set the text div in place of how this post is managing images and its all about an idea ..you can go through this tut and let me know if u face any problem :)

Comment: I have used images as of now..u can see it here [link](http://codejigz.com/demos/wheeloffortune/wheel.html) but i have a prob..On clicking stop button, the wheel shd\udnt stop at abruptly..Instead it shud slow down..

Answer (score 0):

I created a roulette wheel using Raphael at: http://www.guesttime.com/members/ledlogic/roulette/index.html

It has the text rotated like you do, but you'd have to handle the centering for each letter.