# Troubles with wheel of fortune

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I use the wheel of fortune by Roco K. Bullian from here:
[how to draw a wheel of fortune?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850201/how-to-draw-a-wheel-of-fortune)

This is my first experience with js and canvas, and I have two questions.

First:
How can I get the value after spinning? I tried using setTimeout for this, but I just don't understand when it stops.

Second:
I want to put long sentences in labels, but they go out of bounds.

I've tried using a flexible font, but that doesn't really work and isn't exactly what I need. I need the text inside each block to move to a new line and reduce the font if it goes out of bounds.

Can all of this be implemented in this code, or would I need to write everything from scratch?

Code

Js:

```
  const sectors = [
  {color:"#f82", label:"Stack"},
  {color:"#0bf", label:"10"},
  {color:"#fb0", label:"200"},
  {color:"#0fb", label:"50"},
  {color:"#b0f", label:"100"},
  {color:"#f0b", label:"5"},
  {color:"#bf0", label:"500"},
];

const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
const tot = sectors.length;
const EL_spin = document.querySelector("#spin");
const ctx = document.querySelector("#wheel").getContext('2d');
const dia = ctx.canvas.width;
const rad = dia / 2;
const PI = Math.PI;
const TAU = 2 * PI;
const arc = TAU / sectors.length;

const friction = 0.991; // 0.995=soft, 0.99=mid, 0.98=hard
let angVel = 0; // Angular velocity
let ang = 0; // Angle in radians

const getIndex = () => Math.floor(tot - ang / TAU * tot) % tot;

function drawSector(sector, i) {
  const ang = arc * i;
  ctx.save();
  // COLOR
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
  ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
  ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
  ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
  ctx.fill();
  // TEXT
  ctx.translate(rad, rad);
  ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.font = "bold 30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
  //
  ctx.restore();
};

function rotate() {
  const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
  ctx.canvas.style.transform = `rotate(${ang - PI / 2}rad)`;
  EL_spin.textContent = !angVel ? "SPIN" : sector.label;
  EL_spin.style.background = sector.color;
}

function frame() {
  if (!angVel) return;
  angVel *= friction; // Decrement velocity by friction
  if (angVel < 0.002) angVel = 0; // Bring to stop
  ang += angVel; // Update angle
  ang %= TAU; // Normalize angle
  rotate();
}

function engine() {
  frame();
  requestAnimationFrame(engine)
}

// INIT
sectors.forEach(drawSector);
rotate(); // Initial rotation
engine(); // Start engine
EL_spin.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!angVel) angVel = rand(0.25, 0.35);
});
```

Css:

```
    #wheelOfFortune {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wheel {
  display: block;
}

#spin {
  font: 1.5em/0 sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -15%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px currentColor, 0 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

#spin::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: For your first question, you need to wait until `angVel` hits 0 and then get the index using the `getIndex` function. The index can then be used on the `sectors` array to find the label.

Comment: @Stanislas tried it, but it didn't work, alert triggers instantly


    sectors.forEach(drawSector);
    rotate();
    engine();
    eventListener();
    getStringValue(){
                if (angVel === 0)
                {
                    let node = document.getElementById('spin').innerHTML;
                    alert(node)
                }
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note

I'll **only answer your first question**, as your second question of resizing font on a canvas is a big topic on its own and deserves its own question (though I'm sure it has been answered on StackOverflow before).

## How to get the value after spinning

> First: How can I get the value after spinning? I tried using setTimeout for this, but I just don't understand when it stops.

As I suggested in the comment, all you need to do is check if during the last frame update the wheel stopped spinning.

I've included the snippet below that accomplishes this, but note that I only changed the following:

1. At the start of the `frame` function, I'm now setting an `isSpinning` variable.
2. At the end of the same `frame` function, I'm using this `isSpinning` variable and the current velocity to determine if the wheel has just stopped. If it has, I'm calling a new `finishedSpinning` function.
3. Within this new `finishedSpinning` function, I'm using the existing `sectors` array and `getIndex` to find the active sector. As an example, I'm then throwing an alert with the label, but you could replace this by whatever you need.

I hope this helps!

```js
const sectors = [
  {color:"#f82", label:"Stack"},
  {color:"#0bf", label:"10"},
  {color:"#fb0", label:"200"},
  {color:"#0fb", label:"50"},
  {color:"#b0f", label:"100"},
  {color:"#f0b", label:"5"},
  {color:"#bf0", label:"500"},
];

const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
const tot = sectors.length;
const EL_spin = document.querySelector("#spin");
const ctx = document.querySelector("#wheel").getContext('2d');
const dia = ctx.canvas.width;
const rad = dia / 2;
const PI = Math.PI;
const TAU = 2 * PI;
const arc = TAU / sectors.length;

const friction = 0.991; // 0.995=soft, 0.99=mid, 0.98=hard
let angVel = 0; // Angular velocity
let ang = 0; // Angle in radians

const getIndex = () => Math.floor(tot - ang / TAU * tot) % tot;

function drawSector(sector, i) {
  const ang = arc * i;
  ctx.save();
  // COLOR
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
  ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
  ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
  ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
  ctx.fill();
  // TEXT
  ctx.translate(rad, rad);
  ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.font = "bold 30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
  //
  ctx.restore();
};

function rotate() {
  const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
  ctx.canvas.style.transform = `rotate(${ang - PI / 2}rad)`;
  EL_spin.textContent = !angVel ? "SPIN" : sector.label;
  EL_spin.style.background = sector.color;
}

function finishedSpinning() { // Called when the wheel stops spinning
  const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
  alert(sector.label);
}

function frame() {
  if (!angVel) return;
  const isSpinning = angVel > 0; // Check if the wheel is currently spinning
  angVel *= friction; // Decrement velocity by friction
  if (angVel < 0.002) angVel = 0; // Bring to stop
  ang += angVel; // Update angle
  ang %= TAU; // Normalize angle
  rotate();
  
  if (isSpinning && angVel === 0) { // If the wheel was spinning, but isn't anymore, it has just stopped
    finishedSpinning();
  }
}

function engine() {
  frame();
  requestAnimationFrame(engine)
}

// INIT
sectors.forEach(drawSector);
rotate(); // Initial rotation
engine(); // Start engine
EL_spin.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!angVel) angVel = rand(0.25, 0.35);
});
```

```css
    #wheelOfFortune {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wheel {
  display: block;
}

#spin {
  font: 1.5em/0 sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -15%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px currentColor, 0 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

#spin::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wheelOfFortune">
  <canvas id="wheel" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <div id="spin">SPIN</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, but it works, thank you so much!