# Stop wheel of fortune on a specific sector

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm creating a wheel of fortune game, and I need the wheel to stop on a specific item from the `sectors` array.

As soon as the user clicks "Spin", the backend will return me an index of what item the spinner should land on.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmk69oab/1/)

```js
const sectors = [
  {color:"#b0f", label:"100"} ,
  {color:"#f0b", label:"5", },
  {color:"#bf0", label:"500"},
];

// Generate random float in range min-max:
const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;

const tot = sectors.length;
const elSpin = document.querySelector("#spin");
const ctx = document.querySelector("#wheel").getContext`2d`;

   ctx.canvas.width = 600;
    ctx.canvas.height = 600;
    
    const dia = ctx.canvas.width;

    
const rad = dia / 2;
const PI = Math.PI;
const TAU = 2 * PI;
const arc = TAU / sectors.length;
const friction = 0.991;  // 0.995=soft, 0.99=mid, 0.98=hard
const angVelMin = 0.002; // Below that number will be treated as a stop
let angVelMax = 0; // Random ang.vel. to acceletare to 
let angVel = 0;    // Current angular velocity
let ang = 0;       // Angle rotation in radians
let isSpinning = false;
let isAccelerating = false;

//* Get index of current sector */
const getIndex = () => Math.floor(tot - ang / TAU * tot) % tot;

   const loadImage = (ctx, sector, ang) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, rad - 50, 10); // Or at whatever offset you like
      };
      img.src = sector.image;
    };
    
//* Draw sectors and prizes texts to canvas */
const drawSector = (sector, i) => {
  const ang = arc * i;
  ctx.save();
  // COLOR
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
  ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
  ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
  ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
  ctx.fill();
  // TEXT
  ctx.translate(rad, rad);
  ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.font = "bold 30px sans-serif";
  loadImage(ctx, sector, ang);
  ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
  //
  ctx.restore();
};

//* CSS rotate CANVAS Element */
const rotate = () => {
  const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
  ctx.canvas.style.transform = `rotate(${ang - PI / 2}rad)`;
  elSpin.textContent = !angVel ? "SPIN" : sector.label;
  elSpin.style.background = sector.color;
};

const frame = () => {

  if (!isSpinning) return;

  if (angVel >= angVelMax) isAccelerating = false;

  // Accelerate
  if (isAccelerating) {
    angVel ||= angVelMin; // Initial velocity kick
    angVel *= 1.06; // Accelerate
  }
  
  // Decelerate
  else {
    isAccelerating = false;
    angVel *= friction; // Decelerate by friction  

    // SPIN END:
    if (angVel < angVelMin) {
      isSpinning = false;
      angVel = 0; 
    }
  }

  ang += angVel; // Update angle
  ang %= TAU;    // Normalize angle
  rotate();      // CSS rotate!
};

const engine = () => {
  frame();
  requestAnimationFrame(engine)
};

elSpin.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (isSpinning) return;
  isSpinning = true;
  isAccelerating = true;
  angVelMax = rand(0.25, 0.40);
});

// INIT!
sectors.forEach(drawSector);
rotate(); // Initial rotation
engine(); // Start engine!
```

```css
#wheelOfFortune {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  /* height: 720px;
  width: 720px; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wheel {
  display: block;
}

#spin {
  font: 1.5rem/0 sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -15%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px currentColor, 0 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

#spin::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wheelOfFortune">
  <canvas id="wheel" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <div id="spin">SPIN asd asd asd as dasd as dasd asd asd as d</div>
</div>
```

Where do I start to get this done? The spinner needs to gradually slow down, not stop instantly.

I tried to specify a `winningAngle` variable, and when it matches the current angle, it stops.

However, it didn't work as it stopped instantly.

Comment: the code seems to work

Comment: hi @MattEllen! it works, but I need to specify which item it should land on, as the backend will be handling the logic.

Answer (score 1):

***Tl;Dr:***

```
endAng = currAng + extraFullTurnsAng + prizeIndex * arc + rand(arc)
```

where:

- *`*Ang`* are angles defined in **radians**
- `arc` is `Math.PI * 2 / totSectors`
- `rand(arc)` is an additional random amount of sector degrees in order to not always end right on the sector edge

and ease-animate your wheel of fortune element using CSS `transition` and `rotate`, or JS's **Animations API**.

[image]

---

The question's code (originally answered here: [How to Draw a Wheel of Fortune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850201/how-to-draw-a-wheel-of-fortune/33850748?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C56.9820#33850748)) is using requestAnimationFrame (to handle acceleration, deceleration etc.). **This is not necessarily needed**.

Instead:

get the wheel's current [absolute angle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71167019/383904)

```js
// Generate random float in range min-max:
const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
// Fix negative modulo stackoverflow.com/a/71167019/383904
const mod = (n, m) => (n % m + m) % m;

let ang = 0;

// function spin (index) { .....
const angAbs = mod(ang, TAU)
```

get the server-sent "prize **index**" and calculate that index's absolute angle

```js
let angNew = arc * index
```

since you don't want to end the spin exactly on the sector edge, subtract same random `0`*to*`arc` degrees:

```js
angNew -= rand(0, arc)
```

fix negative degrees using a helper modulo function

```js
angNew = mod(angNew, TAU)
```

Now that we have the two angles (`angAbs` and `angNew`) get the angles difference:

```js
const angDiff = mod(angNew - angAbs, TAU)
```

Now you can easily add that `angDiff` to `ang` and animate, but let's add some additional random number of turns (full revolutions) first:

```js
const rev = TAU * Math.floor(rand(4, 6)) // extra 4 or 5 full turns

// Finally update-increment ang
ang += angDiff + rev;
```

**and animate!**

```js
const spinAnimation = elWheel.animate([{ rotate: `${ang}rad` }], {
  duration: rand(4000, 5000),
  easing: "cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.1, 1)",
  fill: "forwards"
});

spinAnimation.addEventListener("finish", () => {
  // Wheel stopped
});
```

PS:

- in the above code [`TAU`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)#Tau_proposals) is (`Math.PI * 2`)
- `arc` is `TAU / totalSectors`
- By default the angle in the web world is pointing `0` right (east) and advances clockwise. If your wheel pin/needle is located on the top (north) add that angle offset at the moment you need to rotate the wheel: `` elWheel.animate([{ rotate: `${ang + angOffset}rad` }], { `` where `angOffset` might be a constant like `const angOffset = TAU * 0.75; // needle is north`.

---

Tip: if you want to track the wheel spin animation progress you'll need to use requestAnimationFrame regardless, since the Animation instance does not have a direct *"animationTick"* event callback.

```js
// update() { function called at ~60fps using requestAnimationFrame 

const currentProgress = spinAnimation.effect.getComputedTiming().progress;
// value from 0 to 1  
// Get the angle:
const angDiff = ang - oldAng;
const angCurr = angDiff * currentProgress;
const angAbs = mod(oldAng + angCurr, TAU); 
console.log(angAbs);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I have a demo please?

Comment: Here's a [*"rigged"* wheel of fortune JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7vf05jmx/) @ToảnLêVăn all the necessary code was literally in the answer :)

Comment: @roko-c-buljan Hi, in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850748/10839134) answer the sectors are drawn clockwise based on the `sectors` array (e.g. 0: Stack, 1: 10, 2: 200...) but in this answer I notice that the indexing is counterclockwise (e.g. 0: Stack, 1: 500, 2: 5...). I'm combining the two answers but when I do `spin(2)` the result is not equal to `sectors[2]`. What would be the best way to align the `drawSector` indexing with the `spin` indexing?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos can you please create a jsfiddle.net that recreates the issue? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: Yes, https://jsfiddle.net/06qvzcnr/

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos simply use: `let angNew = TAU - arc * index;` instead of `let angNew = arc * index;` https://jsfiddle.net/72Lgt68e/

Answer (score 0):

I spent all week trying to apply this to my Angular project.
And everything works well when wheel have sectors arc equal size, but my wheel sectors are not equal. My sectors have start angle point and end angle point, so I needed to calculate arcs for each sector and then stop wheel on index returned from API. So if someone need similar approach...here is my solution, and I hope it will save someone's time... Here I have 10 sectors, where sector 2 and sector 7 are double size.

```
  public sectors: Sector[] = [
{ id: 1, value: 10, color: '#db7093', startAngle: 330, endAngle: 360 },
{ id: 2, value: 20, color: '#20b2aa', startAngle: 270, endAngle: 330 },
{ id: 3, value: 30, color: '#daa520', startAngle: 240, endAngle: 270 },
{ id: 4, value: 40, color: '#ff340f', startAngle: 210, endAngle: 240 },
{ id: 5, value: 50, color: '#ff7f50', startAngle: 180, endAngle: 210 },
{ id: 6, value: 60, color: '#3cb371', startAngle: 150, endAngle: 180 },
{ id: 7, value: 70, color: '#4169e1', startAngle: 90, endAngle: 150 },
{ id: 8, value: 80, color: '#3cb371', startAngle: 60, endAngle: 90 },
{ id: 9, value: 90, color: '#d63e92', startAngle: 30, endAngle: 60 },
{ id: 10, value: 100, color: '#daa520', startAngle: 0, endAngle: 30 }];
```

In your spin function, instead of calculating arc = TAU / totalSectors, you will need to calculate each sector arc because now they are not equal size.

```
  // Calculate arc for each sector
const sectorArcs = this.sectors.map(sector => {
  const sectorAngleDegrees = sector.endAngle - sector.startAngle;
  const sectorAngleRadians = (sectorAngleDegrees / 360) * TAU;
  return sectorAngleRadians;
});
```

Now you need to calculate cumulative arc

```
   // Calculate cumulative arc for each sector
let cumulativeArcs = [0];
for (let i = 1; i < this.sectors.length; i++) {
  cumulativeArcs[i] = cumulativeArcs[i - 1] + sectorArcs[i - 1];
}
```

Now you need to find yours winning sector, and take index and use that index like this:

```
 let angNew = cumulativeArcs[index + 1];
 // since you don't want to end the spin exactly on the sector edge, 
 subtract same random 0 to sectors arc degrees:
 angNew -= rand(0, sectorArcs[index]);
```

rest of code is the same... Hope it helps.